# how to reduce the result set in hibernate search(lucene)?

Tags: java, hibernate, autocomplete, lucene, hibernate-search

I have 9 millions of products in DB and I am trying to use hibernate search for finding suggestion of the products when user start typing product name in search box in a website. It is a autocomplete feature. I have implemented the web service to get the possible solutions from dataset using hibernate search.

The dataset have the 2 fields

1. Product Name
2. Url link

The data stored in my sql. I am using org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery for the search.

Issues with the results:

1. Number of results are too much. I am getting 18K+ results when I searching "intel core".
2. It causes performance issue in terms of query response. For above search it took 2 seconds.

Is there way to reduce the search results on my dataset for better response time of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setMaxResults()

Doc here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int).

You may want to tweak your query/data to get the "most relevant" records returned.

Comment: Thanks.. it reduced the number of results... there is quite amount of improvement in response time.